Toddler hitting while showing affection Why?
I‘m here because my two year old son hits me during moments of mutual affection and I can’t find anything about it than one other post on here. Since my son was about 8 months old sometimes when we are both having a sweet affectionate moment like a hug or like looking into each others eyes happily he will start hitting me or when he was younger he would head butt me. He is an intuitively kind child who is good at sharing and rarely hits others, it seems like something that is especially reserved for me - his mum. Could it be him feeling intense emotion and not knowing what to do With it? Is it that he knows my love is unconditional so he feels intrigued to test its limits? Im trying to figure out the why so I can respond accordingly. So far ive only had luck with responding as if I know the feeling of love can be overwhelming and telling him I love him too which seems to fulfil something. Other times, I have shown that it hurts me and, it’s almost like he did it as an excuse so he could hug me to make it better so he repeats the negative behaviour and ends it with a hug? Help!

Psychology & Neuroscience doesn't allow questions involving help with your personal circumstances; I think the Parenting Stack Exchange would be a better fit as they seem to accept these sorts of questions as long as they're not asking for medical advice.
